# ReactJS beginner: about how to use customise tag without render function

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner of **ReactJS**, coming from **Angular** directive.

Is there a way i can declare a customise component without the need to use React.render function?

For example in Angular directive: `<test></test>` it would work right away (if i declare a 'test' directive).

But in react do you have to do:

```
React.render('<Test />', document.getElementById('container'));
```

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. `React.render` (or `ReactDOM.render` in 0.14+) is the top-level entry point for rendering a React component. It is not designed to allow you to define tags that you can use in regular HTML. However, you can render *any* component created with `React.createClass` (or the newer ES6 class syntax) via `React.render`.

Even Angular, though, requires a full application instantiation (e.g. via `ngApp` or other more manual means) which includes initializing [a compilation service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) to enable directives.

Comment: got it, thanks :) i guess you need to plan hard before go in react then.

Comment: hey mate, what's your thought over react and angular? are you moving away from angular now or it's still your fav tool, peeked your profile and want to know.

Comment: @bluebill1049 I'm using React almost exclusively. I haven't worked with Angular in a couple years. But, it's looking like Angular 2 will have some of the same good ideas that React promotes. Since it's hard to have this conversation in comments (and probably not the right place anyway :) I'm happy to chat more about it via email or something; you can find [my contact info](http://brandontilley.com/contact.html) on my profile.

Comment: Thank you i sent you a short email just to get some of your ideas, thanks mate for your help